# How to stop my C# form from freezing when running another process?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am launching Selenium from a Windows Form. Once selenium launches, the form is frozen until Selenium finished, then the UI updates and is clickable again.

Code where I launch the driver:

```
using(var drivers = new PhantomJSDriver(@"C:\Users\Me\Documents"))
```

How do I make the UI responsive when PhantomJS is running?

Comment: Probably you should add a bit of your code around the _I am launching Selenium from a Windows Form_ to let us try to understand why your code is not working.

Comment: If you run a blocking operation on your UI thread, it will do exactly that: block your UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make the UI responsive when PhantomJS is running in the
>   background?

Not sure if you are running them in separate thread (since you tagged `C#`); if yes, then make sure you are not waiting on that thread. Means, if you are using `System.Threading.Thread` then you don't have a `Join()` method call on thread instance (OR) if you are using `Task` then you are not calling `WaitAll()` or `WaitAny()`. Cause, if it's present means your UI thread is actually waiting for the bg thread to complete before it can start it's own processing which is what you don't want to do.

Per your comment: In that case, you can chose to run `PhantomJS` on a separate thread than the UI thread. You can use [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose.

Comment: I have not implemented any multithreading. All this is being ran off a button_click event.

Comment: @User, then how you say *PhantomJS is running in the background*?

Comment: You're right, it's not in the background. Poor choice of wording. I called it that, because phantomjs is invisible (headless), but it's not in the background.

Comment: @User: exactly. If it's all running in a button click handler, then it's runnong on the UI thread - preventing the UI from doing something else.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Right, so how do I go about getting it on it's own thread?

Comment: @User: see the related links on the right side

Comment: @User, run it in a separate thread. See edit in answer. Have given MSDN document link which will get you going.